# Description of the function graph

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, trigonometry, dynamical-systems, graphing-functions

I've need to somehow describe this function:[image]
The most similar function I guessed is the equation of the form `y(x) = sin(x) + sin(3x)` [image] (green line) but it doesn't exactly what I needed. Maybe there is someone who knows how to describe it?

Comment: Is the black curve from some class of curves like parabolas, splines, or catenary curves? Do you want the points where the black and green curves meet to be infinitely smooth?

Comment: @CyclotomicField i've edited the question. So yes, you're right about points where the black and green curves meet. And I made black curve as parabola but I'm not sure if that's right cause I suppose that  function would be ```2π``` - periodic

Comment: What about the second curve on this picture? It's the second Fourier series approximation of a square curve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#/media/File:Fourier_Series.svg

Comment: Your $y(x)=-(\sin(x)+\sin(3x))$ suggestion is excellent and $y(x)=-0.9296(\sin(x)+0.5\sin(3x))$ should be a little better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that your graph looks like a sine curve that's been wrapped around a cylinder viewed from above. From that I was able to work out the equation $y = -\sin(e \sin(x))$. Feel free to play around in desmos to modify it to your liking: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jfwbvrmj7d

Is there any particular application you had in mind for this graph?

Comment: thank you very much! that's what I needed! It's for my term paper. I have a dynamic function ```  dφ /dt = γ - F( φ) ```  where F( φ) is the function I was looking for , then I am to find equilibrium states, search for self-oscillation cycles like in the Fitzhugh-Nagumo model and so on

Answer (score 3):

I've looked at the picture and made a crude approximation, but this should allow anyone who knows how to derive the real values used here to have somewhere to start https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jbfrwrju0e

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).